# primorial $\pm1=$ prime (sometimes)

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, soft-question, big-list

I know there are a few questions about this sort of thing already, so excuse me if this is a duplicate.

I noticed something interesting when playing around with primorials and related quantities. I got the idea to do so after seeing the popular proof by contradiction that there are infinitely many primes. Below is a not-really-ordered list of primes that I found while messing around. First off, we have a little pattern involving primorial+1, but it stops at $13\text{#}=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdots13$
$$\begin{align}
3&=2+1=2!+1\\
7&=2\cdot3+1=3!+1\\
31&=2\cdot3\cdot5+1\\
211&=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7+1\\
2311&=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11+1\\
\color{red}{59\cdot509}&\color{red}{\,\,=13\text{#}+1}
\end{align}$$
Then, since the primorial method seemed to fail, I began excluding factors from the primorials, and multiplying by primes that I had previously found:
$$\begin{align}
929&=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot31\color{blue}{-1}\\
1303&=2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot31+1\\
1373611&=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot31\cdot211+1\\
15109709&=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot31\cdot211\color{blue}{-1}\\
41163989&=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot211\cdot929\color{blue}{-1}\\
255216737&=2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot31\cdot211\cdot929\color{blue}{-1}.
\end{align}$$
I then noticed that the following were also primes:
$$\begin{align}
23&=4!-1\\
719&=6!-1\\
5039&=7!-1,
\end{align}$$
As well as
$$\begin{align}
967&=2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot23+1\\
30197&=2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot719\color{blue}{-1}\\
211639&=2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot5039+1.
\end{align}$$
I found these all in about 30 minutes, and I'm sure I could find a lot more if I tried.

I am a firm believer that when it comes to number theory, almost nothing is a coincidence. Intuitively, the occurrences of these primes makes sense: when you add or subtract $1$ to a highly composite number $N$, the result is a lot less likely to have just as many divisors as $N$, and a lot of the time, at least one of $N\pm1$ ends up being prime (Mersenne primes are a great example). However, I lack any deeper understanding of this.

Are there any theorems which have to do with constructing primes from highly composite numbers? Given any finite set of primes, is their product more likely to be $1$ away from a prime than any given integer with the same number of digits?

Really, this question is a resource request on the construction and occurrence of primes.

And of course, if you find any more nice examples using my 'method' above, feel free to add them as an answer.

Comment: There are some open questions about which primes do, and which don't, arise in calculations like yours. I think a search for *Euclidean primes* may turn up some of the previous work on this matter.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euclid-MullinSequence.html is related, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Mullin_sequence and https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/nothingtalk2.pdf

Comment: No, there is no known construction of ANY new big prime. The forms you mentioned just increase the chance drastically that we have a prime, but still a big prime is a coincidence (no one can say why ANY big prime is prime). The factorials $n!\pm 1$ and the primorials $n$#$\pm 1$ have been tested upto millions of digits and the prime cases are listet in tables.

Comment: Mersenne numbers have three advantages : (1) There is an efficient 100% test (2) The prime factors have a special form allowing to accelerate trial division before a test $(3)$ $2^n-1$ can only be prime if $n$ is prime. This has been done and multiply doublecheked upto millions of digits and the largest known prime so far was always a Mersenne number. Maybe, at some time , it will be a generalized Fermat number.

Comment: Have you followed up on my links, clath?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP refuses to engage.

Comment: @GerryMyerson hi, sorry I'm very busy with midterms at the moment and I haven't had time to be very active on here. 
When it comes to the Euclid-Mullin sequence, I assume $$a_n=1+\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k$$ iff $a_n$ is prime. I don't know how this is very useful though. Wouldn't it make more sense to look at $$b_n=1+\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k$$ by itself?

Comment: Also, for others interested the Euclid-Mullin sequence is entry [A000945](http://oeis.org/A000945) in the OEIS. According to the article, as of 2012, the sequence has been evaluated up to 51 terms, and the 52nd term is 335 digit number

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've looked lightly over the slideshow, but I have yet to look at it in more detail. I'll update you once I do